# Java IOException: How to find the root cause?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, ioexception

I am running into an issue where my Java code is throwing an IOException.  The issue I have is that on my test machine, no error is throw.  On my other machine (my real machine where its a lot beefier) I always get an IOException.  The call is very straight forward.
Here is the code:

```java
URL obj = new URL("http://smoutsidebox:50000/validatecallservelet");
URLConnection uc = obj.openConnection();

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) uc;
System.setProperty("http.agent", "");
con.setDoOutput(true); 
con.setDoInput(true); 
con.setRequestMethod(Constants.HTTP_POST_METHOD);
con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionId);

writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream()); //ERROR OCCURS HERE!!
```

And when I call

```java
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
```

I get this stack trace:

```
IOException: java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:168)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:471)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:417)
sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:139)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:423)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:651)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:322)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:283)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:355)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:336)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:331)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:623)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:600)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:671)
```

Is there any way to see if the issue is a firewall or another network issue? Is there a way I can extract more information so that I can find the root cause?  I can't for the life of my understand why it works on one machine but not the other.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Call `connect()` before `getOutputStream()`.

Comment: ...and if you really need to see the call stack, debug mode is SUPER helpful

Comment: @Andreas Why? That will make zero difference apart from timing. `getOutputStream()` calls `connect()`, as the stack trace shows.

Comment: Have you tried to "talk" directly to the service with telnet - i.e. "telnet smoutsidebox 50000" from the command line?  If that doesn't work it may point you in a different direction.  If that code works on one box but not another then yes, it could be DNS or a firewall issue.

Comment: Can you access the URL from your real machine? Are you behind a proxy or firewall or NAT that you can't access outside URLs?

Comment: You can use `$java <ClassName> -Djavax.net.debug=all` - to enable debug mode (assuming its not a proxy or firewall issue and you are able to telnet to the server).

Comment: PS: By the looks of it you appear to be using JDK8 - (since [JDK6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java) and [JDK7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java?av=f) don't even have line 168 for PlainSocketImpl). Can you confirm ?